# flutter cannot write in hive: HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: RecipeModel. Did you forget to register an adapter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a model of Recipes and as the name suggests the model is for recipes. The recipe model has

1. name,
2. authorName,
3. category
4. List --> separate model
5. Lis --->separate model

And `toJson` and `fromJson` methods. Now I want a list which will be saved locally, the list will be of all the recipes the user has marked as favorite.

So, I made this FavoriteRecipeModel:

```
class FavoriteRecipeModel {
  List<RecipeModel>? recipeList;
  FavoriteRecipeModel({this.recipeList});
  factory FavoriteRecipeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      FavoriteRecipeModel(
        recipeList: json["recipeList"] == null ? null : json["recipeList"],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "recipe": recipeList == null ? null : recipeList,
      };
}
```

And this is how the function is written:

```
  FavoriteRecipeModel frm = FavoriteRecipeModel();
  void addToFavorites() async {
    await Hive.initFlutter();
    var box = await Hive.openBox('favoriteRecipeList');
    box.put('frm1', widget.recipe!);
    print(frm);
  }
```

The widget.recipe! is coming in like this:

```
  final RecipeModel? recipe;

  RecipeDetailsScreen({required this.recipe});
```

I'm using the recipe model to load all the data in the screen.

But I'm getting:

`Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: RecipeModel. Did you forget to register an adapter?`

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

**Update 1:** here's my full FavoritesModel

```
class FavoriteRecipeModel {
  List<RecipeModel>? recipeList;
  FavoriteRecipeModel({this.recipeList});
  factory FavoriteRecipeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      FavoriteRecipeModel(
        recipeList: json["recipeList"] == null ? null : json["recipeList"],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "recipe": recipeList == null ? null : recipeList,
      };
}

class FavoriteAdapter extends TypeAdapter<FavoriteRecipeModel> {
  @override
  final typeId = 0;
  @override
  FavoriteRecipeModel read(BinaryReader reader) {
    return FavoriteRecipeModel();
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, FavoriteRecipeModel obj) {
    // TODO: implement write
    writer.write(obj.recipeList);
  }
}
```

and here's the method that should list the all recipe's selected as favorite:

```
  FavoriteRecipeModel frm = FavoriteRecipeModel();
  void addToFavorites() async {
    Hive.registerAdapter(FavoriteAdapter());
    await Hive.initFlutter();
    var box = await Hive.openBox<FavoriteRecipeModel>('favoriteRecipeList');
    box.put('frm1', FavoriteRecipeModel());
    print(box.values);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the hive [docs](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/type_adapters), as you are trying to serialize a custom object Hive does not know how to do that. In which case you should create and register a `TypeAdapter`.

Comment: yes, I tried to implement a custom adapter but I'm finding it  quite complex compared to the sample provided in the docs